# Is it possible to display unicode in MATLAB plot labels?

Tags: matlab, unicode

I would like to call something like

```
xlabel( 'Time (μs)' );
```

But that just shows up with a question mark on the plot. Is there anyway to have the unicode show up?

Comment: For the more general case of Unicode which isn't available through MATLAB's limited LaTeX capabilities, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014476/is-it-possible-to-print-unicode-text-or-characters-in-matlab and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863147/matlab-how-to-display-utf-8-encoded-text-read-from-file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your specific example, you can get the display you want using TeX\LaTeX formatting:

```
xlabel('Time ({\mu}s)');
```

For the more general case of displaying Unicode characters, if you know [the code for your character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) you can convert the decimal value for the code to a character using the function [`char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) and [build a string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) like so:

```
xlabel(['Time (' char(181) 's)']);  % Same results as above
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need the curly brackets around \mu. `\mus` will work.

Comment: @Jonas: True. Somehow a while ago I got into the habit of using curly braces to group TeX symbols, but I don't really remember *why*. Maybe it was just to set it apart from the regular text and make it easier to read, or maybe to account for the off chance that the TeX symbol and regular string combination might give me a different TeX symbol. Old habits... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
 xlabel( 'Time (\mu s)',  'interpreter','tex' );
```

or simply

```
xlabel( 'Time (\mu s)');
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for what I wanted. I'm leaving the question open because it doesn't seem like arbitrary unicode can be displayed in this way (though I may be wrong on this).

Comment: Quick note: I actually wanted \mus not \mu s, I don't want a space between the μ and the s.

Comment: the space is only for the tex interpreter to identify the symbol, the output should not contain a space.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer TeX\LaTeX formatting.

In general MATLAB does not have a consistent system for displaying Unicode characters.  In his answer gnovice mentions using the `char` function but beware that this will actually display whatever character corresponds to that decimal value on your current system (based on your Locale).

On Windows that means you'll probably actually want to reference the [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) code page when choosing your decimal value.  You can use [this resource](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) if you decide to use LaTeX.