# MATLAB: checkmark in MATLAB figure with LaTeX interpreter

Tags: matlab, fonts, latex, figure

In my figure I have a text annotation using the LaTeX interpreter, and it doesn't recognize \checkmark because MATLAB doesn't have the amsmath package.

Are there any ideas for a workaround? Perhaps I can have part of the text box interpreted with LaTeX, and part of it without? In that case I could use [this solution](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/58752).

Comment: Did you try copy-pasting the unicode version (✓)?

Comment: Or even switch to a wingdings-like font, print the appropriate character with it, and switch the font back to the original?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472026/french-accents-in-matlab-gui/17488884#17488884

Answer (score 2):

it's not pretty, but might be good enough:

```
xlabel('$\surd$','interpreter','latex')
```

or look here for other things that look like a tick
http://detexify.kirelabs.org