# matlab, utf-8, Cyrillic

Tags: matlab, utf-8, cyrillic

> > load file.txt

Error using load

Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file

only.words.txt

"ÐºÐ°Ñ‚ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ñ ".

How can I load a text file saved in utf-8 (Cyrillic) into matlab and use the TMG matlab toolbox? I'm aware of a similar answer posted some time ago here. It doesn't solve my problem. TMG still doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863147/matlab-how-to-display-utf-8-encoded-text-read-from-file this helps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB: how to display UTF-8-encoded text read from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863147/matlab-how-to-display-utf-8-encoded-text-read-from-file)

Comment: Thank you. Still TMG isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle UTF strings properly, you have to read them from your text file using a binary approach, as follows:

```
fid = fopen('mytext.txt','rb');
bytes = fread(fid,'*uint8')';
fclose(fid);

txt = native2unicode(bytes,'UTF-8');
```

At this point, your string will contain the correct values, but Matlab will still be unable to show it properly. To fix this problem, you either have to use the `Java Swing` underlying labels with a font that supports unicode characters:

```
import('java.awt.*');
import('java.swing.*');

lbl = JLabel();
lbl.setFont(Font('Arial Unicode MS',Font.PLAIN,30));
lbl.setText(txt);
```

or the undocumented function that modifies the default character set used by Matlab (which is, by default, set to `ISO-8859-1`):

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess the problem is a specific package I'm using. I'm using the TMG package in matlab and it's not working with the Cyrillic characters.

Comment: this [workaround](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/340903-unicode-characters-in-m-file) solves the problem by FORCING the required encoding: