# Arabic/Persian label Matlab figure

Tags: matlab-figure

Matlab cannot display Arabic/Persian labels of the figure. Also I cannot see my installed fonts and I don't want to add the labels by another program. How can I fix this problem?

[image: Matlab-figure-Arabic-Persian-label-problem]

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a way to display **unicode characters** in axes labels.

It seems that this problem was encountered before, but there's no simple solution for it. See workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014476/is-it-possible-to-print-unicode-text-or-characters-in-matlab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863147/matlab-how-to-display-utf-8-encoded-text-read-from-file).

One important thing though - do **not** edit `.m` files containing unicode\utf-8 characters (such as Arabic, Farsi, Hebrew, Chinese, etc...) in MATLAB, because it messes up the characters upon saving. Use an external editor (like Notepad++) to edit and save the files (as UTF-8 without BOM), and only run in MATLAB.