# Printing Umlauts in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf-generation, ghostscript, cmyk

I’m am trying to create a pdf file from matlab figure using cmyk colors, but facing a problem with umlauts and also some other special characters. Is there any other way to handle this than Latex? The following example demonstrates the issue.

```
plot(rand(199,1))
title_string = ['Some text:äö' char(228) ':2005' char(150) '2008:end text'];
title(title_string);
print(gcf,'-dpdf','cmykfile.pdf','-r600','-cmyk'); 
print(gcf,'-dpdf','rgbfile.pdf','-r600');
```

As you can see from the pdf-files the RGB-version handles umlauts, but not en-dash, and CMYK skips them all.

PDF is generated in Matlab using Ghostscript, but I have not found how to configure character encoding for GS.

I am using Windows and Matlab R2014.

Comment: This is a part of a larger problem of printing `unicode` characters in MATLAB. See these posts on the topic: [q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014476/is-it-possible-to-print-unicode-text-or-characters-in-matlab), [a1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6872642/3372061)

Comment: besides the links in the comment above, you can check out project waterloo: http://waterloo.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have read pages of posts on this and other forums, but these ones were new to me. The first one seems most interesting and javacomponent already gave promising results.

Comment: Text in javaobjects does not print as vector graphics...

Comment: I'd really go for latex. With matlab2tikz and good settings in pgfplots a plot is not just ok, but really publication quality. The matlab export features are the worst features I ever found.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid latex? Perhaps the reason for that is easier to solve instead.

Comment: I have not been able to change the font in latex (to Arial type font). So far the best solution is to print RGB pdf and convert that to CMYK using Acrobat Pro.

Comment: Changing the font may actually be possible, but it is definitely not trivial: http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/114116

Comment: Unicode appears to be (better?) supported in R2015a

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure this is the solution you was looking for.
Anyway, if you create an `eps` first and then convert it to `pdf` the output file doesn't have any issue with the special characters in the title, provided that you **don't** build your title string using `char`.

```
plot(rand(199,1))
title_string = 'Some text:äöä:2005—2008æ:end text';
title(title_string);
print(gcf,'-depsc','cmykfile.eps','-r600','-cmyk'); 
!ps2pdf cmykfile.eps cmykfile.pdf
```

The code above works if you have the `ps2pdf` utility in your system path. You already have `ps2pdf` on your computer if you have MiKTeX installed, but you might need to update your system path. Basically `ps2pdf` should be a shortcut to `gs`, therefore also if you have only `gs` and not MiKTeX installed, you should be able to achieve the same result.

---

EDIT

On my machine (Windows 7, MATLAB R2014b), also this code works well, without the need to use `ps2pdf`:

```
plot(rand(199,1))
title_string = 'Some text:äöä:2005—2008æ:end text';
title(title_string);
print(gcf,'-dpdf','cmykfile.pdf','-r600','-cmyk');
```

It seems that the issue happens when you build the title string using `char`.