# Greek labels on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a graph that I want to plot with Greek labels on it-but I keep getting the graph with `?` instead of the letters.

[image]

How can I get the Greek labels?

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: The code is not mine-so I am not sure if I can.

Comment: Insert a part where you print and label axises, otherwise it will be tough to guess what is going wrong

Comment: Please indicate also your OS and Matlab Release.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651238/is-it-possible-to-display-unicode-in-matlab-plot-labels and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984532/unicode-characters-in-matlab-source-files

Comment: [**Here are some more approaches to try out to solve your problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103033/greek-letters-in-axes-labels-are-not-working/21103117#21103117).

Comment: @Ratbert, MacOS and 2014b.

Comment: Actually my problem is not the axis labels but just the individual bar labels.

Answer (score 0):

See the second table "Character Sequence, Symbol"
The interpreter is set to 'tex' by default,

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#prop_Interpreter